# Is there a way to exclude display: none elements on PDF using DOM PDF

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf, inline-styles

I have a collapsible/expandable table.
When I collapse (hide) row I apply in-line "diplay: none" CSS style using jQuery.

I want to generate PDF using DOM PDF but when I pass DOM object to PDF I get all rows. 
I would like to have only rows/html elements that don't have style "display: none" applied on them.

Is that possible?

Thx!

Comment: Why not simply remove them from the document before passing it along? Also, seriously, `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: So you're modifying the table display dynamically. Then you capture the contents of the DOM through JS and pass it to dompdf? dompdf should have no problem with `display: none;` on a table row. You may want to echo out what you're passing to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: Brian, everything what you said is true. I'm var_dumping DOM object which is passed to dompdf before converting to PDF but I can see display:none rows (in var_dump and on the PDF).

Comment: dompdf should be able to handle what you are sending. Have you tried just echoing back the content you sent to the server to see how it renders in the browser? (Sorry for the loooong delay in responding.)